# What is the best python tool for basic video editing?

Tags: python, video, video-processing, video-editing

The two things I'd like to do in particular are:

- slice up an individual video into many smaller videos
- Draw basic shapes on top of the video

I would prefer to use python because I already know it and it is well-suited for the rest of the work that is happening around this video.

Comment: http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/

Answer (score 4):

Try [Media Lovin' Toolkit](http://www.mltframework.org/), which has Python bindings.

Comment: I cannot find the python bindings...

Comment: @Julien there's not much documentation around, [some examples here](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/tree/master/src/swig/python). Please note that the answer is almost 3 years old and things might have changed in the meantime. I have not looked into that project since two years ago at least, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe OpenCV could help you.

The main project page : http://opencv.org/
And the bindings for Python : https://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/

Cheers,

K.